# Seven-Segment Display doesn't work on two lights

Tags: arduino-uno, 7-segment

This is my code:

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
}
```

This is my circuit:
[image]

Problem:

[image]

Light A and B doesn't work when I plug the red cable to 4 and 5.
All the other lights works just fine.

Comment: Did you try using a different part?

Comment: Do you mean to another 7-segment display ?
I don't have one right now but I can buy one tomorrow. I was hoping that I have any type of error. I don't have any error ?

Comment: You don't have enough code to have any fatal errors. You haven't proven that the pins are the correct ones though.

Comment: Be sure you have a current-limiting resistor in series with any LED segments that you light up, in either the ground side or the high side.  Do segments A or B light up when you apply 5 V instead of trying to drive them with an Arduino IO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [jwpat7 states](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39194/seven-segment-display-doesnt-work-on-two-lights#comment79319_39194), you need a current-limiting resistor for *each* segment, between the data pin (on the Arduino) and the segment pin (on the display). Your Fritzing diagram only shows *one resistor* in the circuit, from the common cathode to GND on the Arduino.

You can not, or should not, *share one resistor to ground* (assuming that you have a common cathode seven segment display). You need a current-limiting resistor on *each anode* (again, (assuming that you have a common cathode seven segment display).

If you are sharing the current-limiting resistor between all segments, and then try to light more than more segment, at a time (which it sounds like you are doing ("when I plug the red cable to 4 and 5"), then the current through the current-limiting resistor will increase, and as a result, the voltage will change significantly enough, such that there is not sufficient voltage drop across the LED in order to make it light up.

Remember, 0.7 V is dropped across the LED.

Test each on the segments, **one at a time**, to make sure they all work, as [Ignacio states in his comment](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39194/seven-segment-display-doesnt-work-on-two-lights/39198#comment79313_39194).

Also, your sketch should be more complete, along the lines of:

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
}
```

Connect up all of the pins, using a current-limiting resistor on each anode, and then try it programmatically.

If your seven segment display is a common anode, then, again, you need a resistor between each cathode and the data pins, and bring the pins `LOW` to light the corresponding segment, i.e.

```
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
```